# Specifying deduction guides for template classes with function pointers

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class:

```
double* createSomething(){return new double{};}
template<typename T>
class B {
    public:
    using BuilderFcnT = T (*)();
    explicit B(BuilderFcnT a) : ab(a) {}

    private:
    BuilderFcnT ab;
    
};
//This did not work:
//template<typename T>  B(typename B<T>::BuilderFcnT) -> B<typename std::__invoke_result<typename B<T>::BuilderFcnT>::type>;

int main(){
    B<double*> b{&createSomething};
    //B b{&createSomething}; <- I would like this 
    return 0;
}
```

I would like the user to use it as follows
(I would like to avoid specifying the type and have the compiler deduce it):

```
B b{&createSomething};//createSomething takes no arguments and returns a pointer to an object
```

But I am getting [warning in Clang compiler with the flag -Wctad-maybe-unsupported](https://godbolt.org/z/cq8Yee3Ms) , and a warning in gcc. It says that I should specify deduction guides for the template class. I tried the following:

```
template<typename T>  B(typename B<T>::BuilderFcnT) -> B<typename std::__invoke_result<typename B<T>::BuilderFcnT>::type>;
```

But I cannot get it to parse. Is there something trivial that I am missing?

Comment: Please add the declaration of `createSomething`, and show the error messages/warnings you get.

Comment: cannot reproduce : https://godbolt.org/z/bKboW5vnr. Please post a [mcve] and the compiler error message

Comment: When you got the errors/warnings, were you compiling with C++17 mode turned on?

Comment: sorry I just added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I added the -std=c++17. But it still errors with clang. With gcc it only gives a warning.

Comment: What versions are you using?  I cant get an error from clang [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8onTGPEov) going all the way back to version 5.

Comment: Here is the link with the warning I was talking about.  https://godbolt.org/z/cq8Yee3Ms

Comment: but thats only a warning due to `-Wctad-maybe-unsupported` Why do you use that flag when you want to use ctad?

Comment: Why are you specifying `-Wctad-maybe-unsupported` in the first place? It is for people who do NOT want their classes to do CTAD without explicit deduction guides.

Comment: I was cleaning up as much warning as I could by using clang WARN_LEVEL SUPER-STRICT. I was curious of how you could make this one go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with `B(typename B<T>::BuilderFcnT)` is you are trying to use a type that depends on `T`, but you are in the process of deducing `T`.  It's like the chicken and egg problem.  In this case you just need

```
template<typename T>  B(T(*)()) -> B<T>;
```